# Array filtering with conditions

Tags: python, numpy

(I'm not sure about the correctness of title)

I have an `numpy.array` `f` as follows:

```
# id frame x y z
```

What I want to do is to extract the trajectories for some specific `id`. For `id==1` I get for instance:

```
f_1 = f[ f[:,0]==1 ]
```

and get

```
array([[   1.     ,   55.     ,  381.51   , -135.476  ,  163.751  ],
       [   1.     ,   56.     ,  369.176  , -134.842  ,  163.751  ],
       [   1.     ,   57.     ,  357.499  , -134.204  ,  163.751  ],
       [   1.     ,   58.     ,  346.65   , -133.786  ,  163.751  ],
       [   1.     ,   59.     ,  336.602  , -133.762  ,  163.751  ],
       [   1.     ,   60.     ,  326.762  , -135.157  ,  163.751  ],
       [   1.     ,   61.     ,  315.77   , -135.898  ,  163.751  ],
       [   1.     ,   62.     ,  303.806  , -136.855  ,  163.751  ],
       [   1.     ,   63.     ,  291.273  , -138.255  ,  163.751  ],
       [   1.     ,   64.     ,  278.767  , -139.824  ,  163.751  ],
       [   1.     ,   65.     ,  266.778  , -141.123  ,  163.751  ],
       [   1.     ,   66.     ,  255.773  , -142.42   ,  163.751  ],
       [   1.     ,   67.     ,  244.864  , -143.314  ,  163.751  ]])
```

My problem is I' m not sure I understand how it works. Normally I was expecting something like:

```
f_1 = f[ f[:,0]==1, : ]
```

which also works and makes more sense to me. (take all columns but only those rows that fulfill the required condition)

Can someone explain why this form also works and what exactly happens?

```
f_1 = f[ f[:,0]==1 ]
```

Comment: See what `f[:,0] == 1` gives you in an interactive session. Then read [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays), then look up numpy broadcasting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a 2D array asking only one index returns the line (with all columns) corresponding to that index, so that:

```
np.all( a[0] == a[0,:] )
#True
```

When you do `a[0]==1` you get a boolean array, like:

```
b = a[0]==1
#array([True, True, False, False, True], dtype=bool)
```

Which you can use through fancy indexing to obtain all the lines whose index has a corresponding `True` value in `b`. In this example, doing:

```
c = a[ b ]
```

will get lines corresponding to indices `[0,1,4]`. The same result would be obtained by passing directly these indices, like `c = a[ [0,1,4] ]`.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the [Tentative Numpy Tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20150802020005/http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial):

> ...When fewer indices are provided than the number of axes, the missing indices are considered complete slices...

So `f[f[:,0]==1]` gets translated to `f[f[:,0]==1,:]` (or equivalently, to `f[f[:,0]==1,...]`) which are all the same thing from programmers' perspective.